# What can I do to fix my Rock, Paper, Scissors code to keep score and to end the game

Tags: python

Here's my code for a Rock, Paper, Scissors game and I am confused on how to create a running score as well as a way to end the game once the user enters 0.

```
import random

def main():
  print ("Welcome to the Rock, Paper, Scissors Tournament!")
  computerTotal = 0
  playerTotal = 0
  playerChoice = playerSelection()
  while (playerChoice != 0):
      computerChoice = computerSelection()
      winner = roundWinner()
      if (winner == 'computer'):
          computerTotal = computerTotal + 1
      elif (winner == 'player'):
          playerTotal = playerTotal + 1
      playerChoice = playerSelection()
      matchWinner = (computerTotal, playerTotal)


def computerSelection():
    choice = random.randint(1,3)
    if choice == 1:
      print ("Computer chose rock")
    elif choice == 2:
      print ("Computer chose scissors")
    elif choice == 3 :
      print ("Computer chose paper")
    return choice

def playerSelection():
    choice = input ("Enter 1 for rock, 2 for scissors, 3 for paper (0 to end the Tournament): ")
    if choice == 0:
      print  ('Final score:', matchWinner() )
    elif choice == 1:
      print ('Player chose rock')
    elif choice == 2:
      print ('Player chose scissors')
    elif choice == 3:
      print ("Player chose paper")
    return playerSelection

def roundWinner():
  if playerSelection() == computerSelection():
    print("Draw no one wins!")
  elif playerSelection == 1 and computerSelection == 3:
    print("Computer Wins!")
  elif playerSelection == 1 and computerSelection == 2:
    print("Player Wins!")
  elif playerSelection == 3 and computerSelection == 1:
    print("Player Wins!")
  elif playerSelection == 3 and computerSelection == 2:
    print("Computer Wins!")
  elif playerSelection == 2 and computerSelection == 1:
    print("Computer Wins!")
  elif playerSelection == 2 and computerSelection == 3:
    print("Player Wins!")


def matchWinner():
  if computerTotal > playerTotal :
    print (" Computer wins the game!" )
  elif computerTotal == playerTotal:
    print (" Draw no one wins!" )
  elif computerTotal < playerTotal:
    print (" Player wins the game!" )
```

I want to also display the match winner once the user has typed 0 and the game has ended.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I don't get what you're asking; you've got running scores (`computerTotal` and `playerTotal`) and you've got a `matchWinner()` function that gives you the final winner once the player presses 0. Are you by any chance asking for an explanation?

Comment: i just need help finishing it to be quite honest.

Comment: Sorry but what's to finish? If I'm not mistaken you've already done everything you've stated in your question. Maybe if you want to clean up your code a bit, there are the answers but you're doing what you want in that code.

Comment: It for some reason is not working out for me and i can't figure out where I'm going wrong. I try to run the code, but it does not print the players choice, tally the score after the round is over, and i cant get the program to stop once the player hits 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is bad.

- Remove : `computerChoice = computerSelection()` and `playerChoice = playerSelection()` because they are calculated in `roundWinner`. Your are actually doing 2 plays per loop.
- Unindent : `matchWinner(computerTotal, playerTotal)`

```
while True:
    winner = roundWinner()
    if (winner == 'computer'):
        computerTotal = computerTotal + 1
    elif (winner == 'player'):
        playerTotal = playerTotal + 1
    elif (winner == 'exit'):
        break
matchWinner(computerTotal, playerTotal)
```

Also fix `roundWinner` to return 'exit' in case player pressed 0. In that case, the exit decision should rise up to all higher functions.